# ImportError: cannot import name 'maxpool_2d' with TensorFlow deep learning colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm a beginner working on cat and dog classifier. My code is given below:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d,maxpool_2d
convnet=conv_2d(convent,32,5,activation='relu')
convent=max_pool_2d(convent,5)
```

While running this in google colab, I got the following error. please help.

> ```
>     ImportError                               
>     <ipython-input-8-dc6c9fb9359a> in <module>()
>       1 
>       2 import tflearn
> ----> 3 from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d,maxpool_2d
>
>      ImportError: cannot import name 'maxpool_2d'
>      NameError                                 
>      <ipython-input-64-4f4aec72da8c> in <module>()
> ----> 1 convnet=conv_2d(convent,32,5,activation='relu')
>       2 convent=max_pool_2d(convent,5)
>     NameError: name 'convent' is not defined
>     NameError                                
>     <ipython-input-4-be31c35783ac> in <module>()
> ----> 1 convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
>       2 convent=max_pool_2d(convent,5)
>     NameError: name 'conv_2d' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. It should be `max_pool_2d` instead of `maxpool_2d`
2. you are setting `convnet` as incoming tensor argrument but it is not declared earlier.

Comment: train_file="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U7i-sJ2QVL_uZfwhCaPp13-2oN0OdlVD"
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(train_file,'r')as z:
  z.extractall()------>it says no such file directory found and train_data not defined.....wat  should i do?